# How does one print a struct member after reading from binary file (using ab+) in C

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles

Hello I am trying to write code to save a `struct` to a binary file then print it after reading from file. When I run my code I get a segmentation fault (11).
this is my code (sorry for all the `printf`s, I was trying to find where the code went wrong)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    struct contact {
        int unqID;
        char *name;
        char *relationship;
        char *phone_number;
        char *email;
    };

    FILE *file;

    file = fopen("test.bin", "ab+");

    struct contact conwrite;
    conwrite.unqID = 0;
    conwrite.name = "president";
    conwrite.relationship = "";
    conwrite.phone_number = "";
    conwrite.email = "";

    struct contact conwrite2;
    conwrite2.unqID = 1;
    conwrite2.name = "vice president";
    conwrite2.relationship = "";
    conwrite2.phone_number = "";
    conwrite2.email = "";

    printf("%s\n", conwrite.name);
    printf("%s\n", conwrite2.name);

    fwrite(&conwrite, sizeof(conwrite), 1, file);
    fwrite(&conwrite2, sizeof(conwrite2), 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    struct contact phonebook[100];

    file = fopen("test.bin", "rb");

    printf("size of file: %lu\n", sizeof(file));
    printf("size of contact: %lu\n", sizeof(struct contact));
    int size = (sizeof(file)) / (sizeof(struct contact));
    printf("size of file: %d\n", size);

    int read = fread(phonebook, sizeof(conwrite), 2, file);
    printf("read: %d\n", read);

    if (phonebook[0].name == NULL)
        printf("phonebook is empty\n");
    else
       printf("phonebook is filled\n");

    printf("%s\n", phonebook[0].name);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Saving pointers to file isn't a good idea. Try to save the *string itself* to the file.

Comment: `sizeof(file)` does NOT tell you the size of the file! Use `stat`.

Comment: `fwrite` and `fread` don't perform serialisation and deserialisation which leads on to the point made by @MikeCAT ... You need to realise that these two tasks are still necessary. Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute the length of the file with the `sizeof` operator:

```
printf("size of file: %lu\n", sizeof(file));
```

Will print the size of a `FILE *`, the number of byte in the pointer itself.  Note that `sizeof` evaluates to a value of type `size_t` for which the proper `printf` format is `%zu`.  If for some reason you cannot use the `z` option, cast the `sizeof` as `(unsigned long)` to use `%lu` but be aware that `size_t` is actually larger than `unsigned long` on some platforms such a `Windows 64 bits`.

To compute the length of the file on disk, you can use a system call such as `stat` or possibly `ftell()` after seeking to the end of the stream with `fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);`. Note that this method only works for tiles open in binary mode. In your program, you do open it in binary mode, but also in update (the `+`), which seems unnecessary.

Finally, you cannot store the information pointed to by these structures with your approach: the strings pointed to by the `struct` members are in memory, you are just writing the values of the pointers, which will not be meaningful when read back by a different program or even a different instance of the same program.  You need to make these strings arrays of `char`, as for example:

```
struct contact {
    int unqID;
    char name[64];
    char relationship[32];
    char phone_number[16];
    char email[64];
};
```

You will need to update your code to account for the difference in types.  Note that this approach introduces a limit on the size of all textual member.  Storing the information in disk files is usually not done this way.  Either use specialized libraries that implement databases, or use an interchange format such as `csv`, `json`, `xml`... by increasing order of complexity and versatility, or a custom text based format.